# Change font size of UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, font-size, uisegmentedcontrol

Can anyone please tell me how can I change the font type and size of `UISegmentedControl`?

Comment: Any solutions in IB instead of code?

Comment: you can not do it in IB.  the current **2021** syntax is: UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: _font], for: .normal)

Answer (score 529):

I ran into the same issue. This code sets the font size for the entire segmented control. Something similar might work for setting the font type. Note that this is only available for iOS5+

**Obj C**:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes 
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

EDIT: `UITextAttributeFont` has been deprecated - use `NSFontAttributeName` instead.

EDIT #2: For Swift 4 `NSFontAttributeName` has been changed to `NSAttributedStringKey.font`.

**Swift 5**:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)
```

**Swift 4**:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font],
                                        for: .normal)
```

**Swift 3**:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font],
                                        for: .normal)
```

**Swift 2.2**:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], 
    forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Thanks to the Swift implementations from @audrey-gordeev

Comment: This works great, though if I have already done a                 `[mySegmentedControl setTintColor:onColor forTag:kTagOnState];` and a `[mySegmentedControl setTintColor:offColor forTag:kTagOffState];` then apply the  `[mySegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];` then the Colors I just set go away.

Comment: You need to use dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys instead and create two arrays with your object and key attributes.

Comment: available in iOS 5.0 or later

Comment: in iOS7: `NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldsystemFontOfSize:12.0f]};`

Comment: @JasonMoore `boldSystemFontOfSize:` (capital S for System)

Comment: Works a treat in iOS 8.  Remind me again, WHY is there no "font" attribute...?   (Apple has a lot of explaining to do...!)

Comment: You can drop the key down to simply `.font` as well

Comment: You actually have to call it like this   
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)

Comment: this answer is wrong in 2021

Answer (score 52):

Use the Appearance API in iOS 5.0+:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:13.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Links:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010906

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Comment: `UITextAttributeFont` has been depreciated - use `NSFontAttributeName` instead.

Comment: Worth noticing that it will change the font of ALL `UISegmentedControl`s.

Answer (score 38):

Here is a Swift version of the accepted answer:

**Swift 3**:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font],
                                        for: .normal)
```

**Swift 2.2**:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], 
    forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to apply a transform to the control. However, it will scale down everything including the control borders.

```
segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.6f, .6f);
```

Comment: Thanks to this simple working code. Scaling it to .75f in iOS6 provides the best result. If used in a table cell, then add 10 to the height of the cell.

Comment: This is not the way you change font size on any control in iOS. Affine transform is mostly intended to be used with animations.

Comment: Please don't scale standard controls.

Comment: @MichaelPeterson would be nice to have much more customizable standard controls, so nobody needs to do hack like this one.

Answer (score 9):

Swift Style:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(objects: [UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)], forKeys: [NSFontAttributeName]), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: You should use swift style dictionary. `[NSFontAttributeName: font]`

Answer (score 8):

Here i have updated for iOS8

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:13.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 7):

XCode 8.1, Swift 3

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(objects: [UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0)], 
        forKeys: [NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying]) as? [AnyHashable : Any], 
        for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

just change the number value `(ofSize: 24.0)`

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 4):

```
// Set font-size and font-femily the way you want
UIFont *objFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DroidSans" size:18.0f];

// Add font object to Dictionary
NSDictionary *dictAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

// Set dictionary to the titleTextAttributes
[yourSegment setTitleTextAttributes:dictAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you have any query, Contact me.

Comment: **objFont** returns `nil` value.

Answer (score 4):

In `swift 5`,

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

C# / Xamarin:

```
segment.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { 
    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(font_size) }, UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Correct answer for 2021. The syntax changed.

The 12 year old answer (even the edits to it) is broken.

It's just:

```
let _font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
UISegmentedControl.appearance()
 .setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: _font], for: .normal)
```

It's very likely you will want to change the height correctly while you are at it:

```
import UIKit

class SmallerSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        common()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common()
    }

    func common() {
        let _font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance()
         .setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: _font], for: .normal)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize:CGSize {
        var s = super.intrinsicContentSize
        s.height = 24
        return s
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Daniel pointed me to correct way. I used it like this-

```
float scaleFactor = 0.8f;

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 300/scaleFactor,35)];

[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"..." atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"..." atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"..." atIndex:2 animated:NO];

segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, 1);
CGPoint segmentedControlCenter = segmentedControl.center;
segmentedControlCenter.x = self.center.x;
segmentedControl.center = segmentedControlCenter;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(objects: [UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)],
                                                                        forKeys: [kCTFontAttributeName as! NSCopying]) as? [AnyHashable : Any],
                                                           for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
UISegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Error : `Instance member 'setTitleTextAttributes' cannot be used on type 'UISegmentedControl'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?` **iOS13/Swift5**

Answer (score 1):

Extension for `UISegmentedControl` for setting Font Size.

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    @available(iOS 8.2, *)
    func setFontSize(fontSize: CGFloat) {
            let normalTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]!
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                normalTextAttributes = [
                    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(fontSize, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
                ]
            } else {
                normalTextAttributes = [
                    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
                ]
            }

        self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Normal)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get at the actual font for the UILabel by recursively examining each of the views starting with the UISegmentedControl. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

```
@interface tmpSegmentedControlTextViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * theControl;

@end

@implementation tmpSegmentedControlTextViewController

@synthesize theControl; // UISegmentedControl

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self printControl:[self theControl]];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) printControl:(UIView *) view {
  NSArray * views = [view subviews];
  NSInteger idx,idxMax;
  for (idx = 0, idxMax = views.count; idx < idxMax; idx++) {
    UIView * thisView = [views objectAtIndex:idx];
    UILabel * tmpLabel = (UILabel *) thisView;
    if ([tmpLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(text)]) {
      NSLog(@"TEXT for view %d: %@",idx,tmpLabel.text);
      [tmpLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }

    if (thisView.subviews.count) {
      NSLog(@"View has subviews");
      [self printControl:thisView];
    }
  }
}

@end
```

In the code above I am just setting the text color of the UILabel, but you could grab or set the font property as well I suppose.

Comment: This is a great way to make sure than an iOS update will break code that you've shipped to your customers. This might work now, but there's absolutely no guarantees that this will continue working in the future.

Answer (score 0):

this is for objective c add your segmented control name in place of *mysegmentedcontrol*

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f];

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                            forKey:UITextAttributeFont];

[mySegmentedcontrol setTitleTextAttributes:attributes                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

hope it helps

Comment: -- update --
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
[mySegmentedcontrol setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];