# Change text color of UISegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Iam new to objective c,need to change the text color of selected segment in UIsegmentControl.
Used following code.

```
 [[UIsegmentControl.subviews objectAtIndex:segment.selectedSegmentIndex] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

it changes segment color.Help me please..

Comment: Updated answer for swift4 with extension,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029760/how-to-change-font-color-of-uisegmentedcontrol/50795377#50795377

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's no way to set the custom color of selected segment title in `UISegmentedControl`. The `UIControlState` in `forState:` used to set the attributes of segment text for normal and selected state.

From Your Code :

```
[[UIsegmentControl.subviews objectAtIndex:segment.selectedSegmentIndex] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Try This Code:

```
[segmnt_cntrl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0],
                                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                                          NSShadowAttributeName:shadow}
                                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Replace the segmnt_cntrl with your object of Segment Cotrol. Try this , It might helps you to achieve your over all goal.

Thanks

Comment: This answer is correct except for your first paragraph. The `UIControlState` in `forState:` can be used to set the attributes for normal and selected segment text.

Comment: What about attribute's range? I want to have two different colors in one title. Is it possible with standard UISegmentedControl?

Comment: hi. WHat is  NSShadowAttributeName: shadow? I can find shadow name attribute

Answer (score 21):

If you need to change the text color of the highlighted segment in iOS 7, here is a solution (took me awhile to find, but [thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156349/uisegmentedcontrol-only-changes-text-color-when-revisiting-viewcontroller)):

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorBlack]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: can you please tell me what to do if I want to change the text color of the highlighted as well as the normal segment to black. Right now it is blue in color

Comment: @NehaDangui, it would be a matter of replacing `UIControlStateSelected` with `UIControlStateNormal` (or `UIControlStateHighlighted` if you need to).

Answer (score 13):

With references to @i--  Answer

**Updated Swift 5**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

**Updated Swift 4.1**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

**Swift 3.1**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red as Any], for: .selected)
```

**For Earlier Swift Version:**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

Comment: Swift 5: `UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Babl Prabhakar's answer

Swift 5: 
`UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard API to set the text attributes of a single segment in a UISegmentedControl. You can do the unrecommended approach of digging into the view hierarchy of the segmented control, find the desired UILabel (if any) and set that label's attributes. A better approach is to find (or write) a custom control that emulates a UISegmentedControl and allows for a single segment to be customized in the way you need.

Edit:

Actually, I was looking at this from the wrong point of view. My answer was based on trying to set attributes for a specific segment index. But in fact this can be achieved by setting the text attributes for the `UIControlStateSelected` state. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can set text attributes using the UIAppearance methods, for a specific control state. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: @jrturton Of course. My mistake. I was thinking about this from the point of view of segment index. But in this case it can be done for the highlighted state. I'll update my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Objective C

set font style, size and color

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size:16] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[self->mySegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes: attributes forState: normal];
[self->mySegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor} forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated @Babul Prabhakar's answer for Swift 3, because about half a dozen tiny things have changed:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red as Any], for: .selected)
```