# UISegmentedControl different font color for selected and unselected segments

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change font color of UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029760/how-to-change-font-color-of-uisegmentedcontrol)

Is it possible to keep different font colors for the text of `selected` and `unselected` `segment` of `UISegmentedControl`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Instantiate as usual
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", @"second", [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"], nil];
MCSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[MCSegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];

// set frame, add to view, set target and action for value change as usual
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, 44.0f);
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Set a tint color
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

// Customize font and items color
segmentedControl.selectedItemColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
segmentedControl.unselectedItemColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

If you use Interface Builder, add a normal UISegmentedControl, set its class as MCSegmentedControl in the Identity Inspector, set the Tint in the Attributes Inspector.

At the moment, animations and the following UISegmentedControl methods are not supported:

```
- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment;
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGSize)offset forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

Here are the files:

[MCSegmentedControl.zip](http://matteocaldari.it/download/MCSegmentedControl.zip)