# How to change the selected segment text colour to highlighted state after selection

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to set the selected segment text colour as white and it will be in highlighted state.If I select the other segment then the selected segment text colour should be highlighted and it should be in highlighted state until i will select the different segment.Is it possible?I don't want to hightlight the selected segment but i want to hightlight the text colour until i will deselect or select another segment.

Answer (score 0):

use `segment.tintColor = [uicolor whitecolor];`

it will help.

Comment: I dont want to highlight the selected segment.I just want to highlight the selected segment text colour

Comment: ok make tow different images, one for normal and second for selected. and change the images accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use it, where objectAtIndex:0 is your selected index.

```
for (UIView *v in [[[segment subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews]) {
   if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
      UILabel *lable=(UILabel *)[v retain];
      lable.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes.It gave me the solution

Comment: But it is not accurate.. Can you give me the better solution

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the below link fixed the problem.[How to change font color of UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029760/how-to-change-font-color-of-uisegmentedcontrol?rq=1)