# Update segmented control in ios without change interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

when I update segmented control text, the interface (segment's width) changed and cut some letters.

```
[segmentedcontoll setTitle:@"test" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
segmentedcontoll.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

How can I solve this ?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? The apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent is the correct way to space your segments based on their content width, but if you have more text than can be displayed over the entire width of the control, some things will be truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your content has outgrown the dimensions of the standard UISegmentedControl.

If you are okay with smaller font, it's possible to set the entire control to have a smaller font point size,  [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280391/change-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol).

Another option is to configure the segments the other supported way.. With images. It's a little bit of a hack, but you can create images on the fly with the UIView Snapshotting API of views/labels configured however you want and set images for each segment instead of using text. This would allow you to create 2 line labels with fixed widths and set images for each section to be images generated from the label as the content changes. More work, but you would still be using the standard class.

The last option, which might work the best for you, is to create some other custom control that does what you would like.  After all, UISegmentedControl really is just a nice button container. And it does somewhat seem like you are using the control in a non-standard way - both as a control and an input form section.

Others have gone this route before and created [alternatives](http://maniacdev.com/2013/02/drop-in-customizable-ios-uisegmentedcontrol-replacement-with-image-support) that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class as below,

```
 class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

 //code for creating multi line

  override func didMoveToSuperview()
  {

    for segment in subviews
    {

      for subview in segment.subviews
      {

        if let segmentLabel = subview as? UILabel
        {

          segmentLabel.numberOfLines = 0 //just change here the number of lines and check it.

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and create an outlet in your viewcontroller as,

```
// Initialize
let items = ["Purple", "Green", "New Segment"]
let customSC = CustomSegmentedControl(items: items)
```

use `customSC` and do what ever you want to do, similar to `segmentedControl` object.