# How do I change the font of a UISegmentedControl in swift without changing the font size?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the font of `UISegmentedControl` without changing the font size.

This is my code but, obviously, in this case i change the font size too:

```
let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , forState: .Normal)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280391/change-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: First get the font size and then change font and set the font size to the one you got before.

Comment: @ayteq how can i get the font size of my UISegmentedControl?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, this is not proper way, but we don't have other option, then we should go via this wat

```
int fontSize;
for (id segment in [segmentedControl subviews]) 
{
    for (id label in [segment subviews]) 
    {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
          fontSize = label.font.pointSize;
          // Here you got the label, now use the font size from here
          break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Now you got the fontSize, now you can use this to change the font face